# Middle page issue

Tags: vue.js

I need the page redirected to the top of page. As we have advanced search option on the home page. Once we click it, it opens the page with middle position But I want to open at the top.

Google

Can't share

Expected results- Page should open at the top of page.

Actual results- Page should open in the middle of page.

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work I tried already.

Comment: @BusinessAnalyst It works just fine when done properly, so you either didn't do it properly, or you're not describing your issue very well. In either case, sharing your code is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You can import jquery into your file and reference a scroll to top function when the component is created. For extra sugar, you can add a sliding animation like so:

```
<script>
import $ from 'jquery'

export default {
  created () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000)
  }
...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Importing jQuery for just this one thing would be fairly silly, especially when Vue has [built-in functionality for this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html).

Comment: [You don't need jQuery for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: I used jquery here as an option and also highlighted that it can come in handy when you not only want to scroll but to animate the scroll.

Comment: @TheWahome A lighter, animation-only library would be a better choice in that situation. Importing all of jQuery adds a *lot* of code to an app for one small thing.